# Go to the last scrolled position java swing JScrollPane

Tags: java, image, swing, jscrollpane, imageicon

I have a `JScrollPane` where I am displaying an Image. The relevant lines of code is

```
ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(in);
scrollPane.setViewportView(new JLabel(ii));
```

This code is called when a button is clicked and it essentially loads the same image with minor modifications.

Suppose an image is loaded and the user scrolls (both horizontal and vertical) to go to a location. Next time the button is clicked and a new image is loaded, the scrollpane forgets the previously scrolled position and starts everything afresh.

I want to view the image in the last scrolled location until another scroll happens. Is that possible?

**EDIT**

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TestScrollPane extends JFrame {
    /**
     * 
     */
    static BufferedImage in = null;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    static String imageLoc=null;
    static Point p= new Point(2,2);
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestScrollPane frame = new TestScrollPane();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */

    private String getAnewImage() throws IOException {
        return "/home/abc/test.jpg"; //change this
    }
    public TestScrollPane() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(0, 0, 1300, 1000);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //all declarations go here
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        final JButton btnInput = new JButton("Test");
        btnInput.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        btnInput.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnInput.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        final JButton btnStart = new JButton("start");
        final JViewport jv= scrollPane.getViewport();

        // all dimensions go here
        scrollPane.setBounds(2, 2, 1150, 950);
        btnInput.setBounds(1160, 100, 90, 50);
        btnStart.setBounds(1160, 300, 90, 25);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);


        jv.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                p=jv.getViewPosition();
            }
        });



        btnInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    in = ImageIO.read(new File(imageLoc));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(in);
                System.out.println("setting viewport to "+p);
                scrollPane.setViewportView(new JLabel(ii));
                scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(p);
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(btnInput);


        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()  {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    imageLoc=getAnewImage();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (imageLoc==null)
                    return;
                else {

                    try {
                        in = ImageIO.read(new File(imageLoc));
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(in);
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(new JLabel(ii));
                }

            }


        });


        contentPane.add(btnStart);


        }
    }
```

Here is the image I used for testing: :[image]. `Start` button loads a new image. After I scroll  and click the "input" button, another image is loaded, but the scrollpane goes back to the top left corner (original position).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the position of the viewport and then restore its location:

```
Point p = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewPostion();
scrollPane.setViewportView(new JLabel(ii));
scrollPane.getViewport.setViewPosition( p );
```

Edit:

I changed your SSCCE to use a `ContainerListener` to reset the viewport view position:

```
jv.addContainerListener( new ContainerAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e)
    {
        scrollPane.getViewport().setViewPosition(p);
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have the point to which I scrolled, but `setViewPosition` doesn't set the location.

Comment: @rivu, Works fine for me using JDK7 on Windows 7. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Only other suggestion is to try wrapping the setViewPosition(...) statement in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to make sure the code is executed after the scrollpane has been revalidated with the new component.

Comment: maybe issue with flush(), this is common issue for JLabel - IMageIcon - (slow resources) with larger files

Comment: @rivu, as suggested by mKorbel it looks like the file may not be completely read when the code is executed which is causing a problem. I change the code to use a `ContainerListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `displayImage` for the label.  When the new image is loaded, paint it to the display image and repaint the label.